# Swift: Enums with stored properties not thread safe even when mutated using a serial queue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, enums

This issue relates to another issue reported on the Apple Developer forum titled [How to avoid Data Races in deinit](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/49930) from 4 years ago. I am seeing crashes in production related to associated data and `outlined consume` code added by the compiler to deinitialize enums with associated data that contain reference types.

When trying to find if someone else has faced the same issue, I stumbled across the above post. I reduced the example from that post to a simpler example below and reliably get a crash due to bad access. (I ran this in Playground and got the crash but no stack trace)

```
import Foundation
class Racer {
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Racer-\(UUID())")
    var value: String? = "" // Desugars to Optional<String>, an enum
    func race() {
        queue.async {[weak self] in
            self?.value = UUID().uuidString
        }
    }
}
let racer = Racer()
while true {
    racer.race()
}
```

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x357d20cc94c0).

Is this a bug in Swift that has yet to be patched?

Comment: What's the specific question here?

Comment: @ItaiFerber I wanted to know if this was a bug in swift. Let me add that to the question

Comment: Excellent. Can you also provide a crash trace? I, for instance, can't reproduce this at all on either debug or release builds.

Comment: I ran this in playground, and I didn't get a stacktrace. Sorry about that. Let me add that too

Comment: Did you try to make a local copy of self ? I have a coworker who told me that he ran into similar problems with weak self. Try with guard let self = self else { return }

Comment: `guard let self = self else { return }` might prevent this crash. But I have seen crashes in our production code due to similar reason. And this is a very simple reproduction of the same issue. I am trying to draw more attention towards [How to avoid Data Races in deinit](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/49930) which seems to be the key issue